# IMAP Proxy for a Server on Windows 7

Tags: email-server, imap, horde

I have configured a set-up of Hmailserver and Horde Groupware Webmail Solution on my test server which runs Windows 7.
Everything is up and running smoothly but I'm encountering two minor issues:

1. In order to optimise the performance of webmail I want to use imapproxy but sadly it is not for windows.

   Can anyone point me to the right direction to configure and run an IMAP Proxy between the email server and the webmail client?
2. The new mail notification is not shown in the Inbox until the page is refreshed.

   Will this problem be solved by the IMAP Proxy or some other tool is required?